# Using delegates to render html blocks in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-2.0, asp.net-3.5

I thought of a neat hack this morning, probably not original, but I haven't seen it before.  I don't consider it good practice, but can help when you need to render a block of code repeatedly around your page, and don't want to touch other code or create other files (partial views or components).

In your .aspx file create an anonymous delegate like so:

```
<%
Action<DataType> renderMe = data => {
  %> Some html text <a href="<%= data.url %>">That can</a> contain quotes, etc. 
     And other <%= data.something %> stuff...
  <%
};
%>
```

Then you can simply use it anywhere you want: (`myvar1` and `myvar2` are of type `DataType`)

```
This is some html and I want the block here: <% renderMe(myvar1); %> ...
or maybe here <% renderMe(myvar2); %>
```

I know it's not a great idea, but can anyone see any problems with doing this?

Comment: Looks too much like PHP to me. I'd rather use a custom control or a repeater.

Comment: I'd like to know what's so bad about PartialViews that you feel you need to use variables.  You can alter where MVC looks for partial views so that you can have a common location for the whole web app so...

Comment: Just makes for possibly muddled markup. Other than that it can be handy in certain situations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ain't bad per se. Quite similar to [Spark's macros](http://sparkviewengine.com/documentation/syntax) (that looks better imho). [Rashud`s script manager](http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2009/04/28/script-and-css-management-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx) (for advanced js initialization) uses the same technique. [MvcContrib's grid renderer](http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/2009/02/22/rewriting-the-mvccontrib-grid-part-2-new-syntax/) does the same too.

Thing is - niche when this is suitable is really narrow. Only when desired snippet of html should be passed to server side or when you want to re-use it twice or more in context of one specific view but don't want to create separate partial view.